# Cracking passwords after a pattern with John

Tags: passwords, linux, password-cracking

So I am trying to find out how easy it is to crack a password using some great Linux tools.

We all know about John as a password cracker and how great it is.  But how about specifying a pattern.

Let's assume the following policies.

- A password must start with a capital letter followed by 3 small letters
- A password must end with 3 numbers
- A password must be exactly 7 in length

Password example: Aabc123

So I have not the slightest clue how to do this.  I tried to Google it, but no success or even hints was made for me.

Is there a way to configure John to do this and how?

Comment: Look at Kore Logic Rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `oclHashcat`'s mask processor available [here](http://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=maskprocessor).

You can use this to create a wordlist with your exact specifications.

```
?u is uppercase
?l is lowercase
?d are digits
```

So you can make a wordlist of the following:

```
mp64.exe ?u?l?l?l?d?d?d > wordlist.txt
```

Run either `oclHashcat` or `JTR` against that wordlist and you're good to go.

Comment: JTR's munging (a.k.a. permutation) rules let you do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

John has a mask too.

> Mask mode is a fast way to produce password candidates given a "mask"
>   that describes what the words should look like.
>
> A mask may consist of:
>
> - Static letters.
> - Ranges in `[aouei]` or `[a-z]` syntax. Or both, `[0-9abcdef]` is the same as   `[0-9a-f]`.
> - Placeholders that are just a short form for ranges, like `?l` which is   equivalent to `[a-z]`.
> - `?l` lower-case ASCII letters
> - `?u` upper-case ASCII letters
> - `?d` digits
> - `?s` specials (all printable ASCII characters not in ?l, ?u or ?d)
> - `?a` full 'printable' ASCII
> - `?A` all valid characters in the current code page
> - `?h` all 8-bit (0x80-0xff)
> - `?H` all except the NULL character (which is currently not supported by core)
> - `?L` non-ASCII lower-case letters
> - `?U` non-ASCII upper-case letters
> - `?D` non-ASCII "digits"
> - `?S` non-ASCII "specials"
> - Placeholders that are custom defined, so we can eg. define `?1` to mean `[?u?l]`   `?1 .. ?9` user-defined place-holder `1 .. 9`
> - Placeholder for Hybrid Mask mode   `?w` is a placeholder for the original word produced by the parent mode in
>     Hybrid Mask mode.
>
> Mask Mode alone produces words from the mask, for example `?u?l?l` will
>   generate all possible three-letter words, with first character
>   uppercased and the remaining in lowercase.
>
> Hybrid Mask means we use eg. a wordlist with or without rules (or some
>   other cracking mode), and then apply the mask to each word. So with a
>   mask of `?w?d?d` and an input word (from the parent cracking mode) of
>   "pass", it will produce "pass00", "pass01" and so on until "pass99".
>   Hybrid Mask can be stacked upon Incremental, Markov, Wordlist and
>   External modes.
>
> External Filters currently can't be applied to Hybrid Mask output.
>
> You can define custom placeholders for `?1 .. ?9` using command line eg.
>   `-1=?l?u` or in john.conf section [Mask].
>
> There is a default mask in john.conf too (defaulting to same as
>   Hashcat: `?1?2?2?2?2?2?2?3?3?3?3?d?d?d?d`). This should be used with
>   `-max-len` and possibly
>   `-min-len`.
>
> The `-max-len=N` option will truncate the mask so no words longer than N
>   are produced.
>
> The `-min-len=N` option will skip generation of words shorter than N,
>   and more importantly in this case, it will iterate length from
>   `-min-len` to `-max-len` (or format's max length, if `-max-len` was not given). So to produce all possible words from 3 to 5 letters, use
>   `-mask=?l?l?l?l?l -min-len=3 -max-len=5`. For this to work, the mask must have at least 5 positions defined.
>
> You can escape special characters with `\`. So to produce a literal "`?l`"
>   you could say `\?l` or `?\l` and it will not be parsed as a placeholder.
>   Similarly you can escape dashes or brackets to prevent them from being
>   parsed as specials. To produce a literal backslash, use `\\`.
>
> There is also a special hex notation, `\xHH` for specifying any
>   character code. For example, `\x41` is "A" and `\x09` is the code for TAB.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> **Mask        custom mask / hybrid input  example output  num candidates**
>
>  pass                                 pass                    1 
>
>  pw%d                                 pw3                     10
>
>  ?w?d?d?d     password                password123            1000x 
>
>  ?w?s?w           bozo                 bozo#bozo              33x
>
>  0x?1?1:?1?1:?1?1 -1=[0-9a-f]         0xde:ad:ca           16777216
>
>  ?3?l?l?l     -3=?l?u                 Bozo, hobo            913952
>
>  [Pp][Aa@][Ss5][Ss5][Ww][Oo0][Rr][Dd]     P@55w0rD           1296
> ```

Even you can use external program to pass the generated passwords to John:

Like this: `crunch 1 6 abcdefg | ./john hashes -stdin -session=s1`

Answer (score 2):

One simple method would be to just generate the wordlist as there's only 26*26*26*26*10*10*10 possibilities, so your wordlist would be about 3.4 GB (8 bytes per password; the seven characters and a line break).

This would be trivial to do in any programming language; e.g., in python I would use:

```
import string
uppers = string.ascii_uppercase # 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
lowers = string.ascii_lowercase # 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
with open('wordlist.out', 'w') as f:
    for c1 in uppers:
        for c2 in lowers:
            for c3 in lowers:
                for c4 in lowers:
                    for d in range(1000):
                        f.write('%s%s%s%s%03d\n' % (c1, c2, c3, c4, d))
```

This method will try every password in alphabetical order -- e.g., Aaaa000 first then Aaaa001, ..., Aaaa999, Aaab000, Aaab001, ..., Azzz999, ... Baaa000.  You can rearrange the nesting of the for-loops if you want to traverse in a different order.

Comment: For future searchers, note that using masks within the cracking tools themselves is usually much faster than generating the equivalent wordlist -
 especially for the algorithms and tools with GPU support.