# Password help with coding!

Tags: passwords, password-cracking

So, I'm terrible with any sort of coding, and I need help with generating a series of possible passwords. I've forgotten the combination of a password I put in for an email - I know the password, just not which letter was capitalized and which weren't.

I'm trying to write some code to output all the possible outcomes of the password with capitals in different places. The password is 7 characters long.

Edit: I know the placing, too, so I don't need a randomizer. Just the capital and lower cases in all possible locations.

Edit 2: I tried

```
def random_char(y):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(y))

print (random_char(7))
```

it didn't work, I need the output to be the specific letters and number I know I put in my password.

Comment: do you know about the program `crunch` https://pentestlab.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/creating-wordlists-with-crunch/?

Comment: The answers here might help you, too: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47416/cracking-passwords-after-a-pattern-with-john?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If the password is 7 characters long - then that is the maximum number of alpha characters possible (some may be numerics). Therefore the maximum number of combinations will be 128 - which surely just takes some determination and a bit of time to work through methodically.

E.g.

passworD
passwoRd
passwoRD
passwOrd
passwOrD
passwORd
passwORD
passWord

Answer (score 0):

Here is an atrocious, tricky, non-standard C code -- which works:

```
static void
print_caps(char *str)
{
        uint64_t x, y;
        int i;
        char buf[8];

        if (strlen(str) != 7) {
                return;
        }
        x = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i ++) {
                x <<= 8;
                x += ((unsigned char *)str)[i];
        }
        printf("%s\n", str);
        y = 32;
        buf[7] = 0;
        do {
                for (i = 0; i < 7; i ++) {
                        buf[i] = (x ^ y) >> ((6 - i) << 3);
                }
                printf("%s\n", buf);
                y <<= 8;
                y ^= (y >> 56) * (257 + ((uint64_t)1 << 56));
        } while (y != 32);
}
```

The amusing part being, of course, understanding *why* it works (and that part can be deemed to have at least some indirect relevance to the field of cryptography).

(Of course it could have been done in a much shorter, more efficient, and boring way.)

Answer (score 0):

Given how you're not a programmer, it's likely easiest if you can just try it on a `bash` command line:

```
$ uc() { echo "$1" |tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'; }
$ pwmorph() { for i in {0..6}; do echo "${1:0:i}$(uc "${1:i:1}")${1:i+1:7}"; done; }
$ pwmorph abcdefg
Abcdefg
aBcdefg
abCdefg
abcDefg
abcdEfg
abcdeFg
abcdefG
```

Though feeding this into the mechanism to try it out may be harder to automate.

- The first line defines a function to uppercase its input.
- The second line defines a function that loops from zero to six, showing the substring before the letter to be uppercased (`${1:0:i}` samples the argument `$1` from zero to `i`), then that letter in upper case (running `uc` on `${1:i:1}`, which is the argument from an offset of `i` and length of 1), then the rest of the string (`${1:i+1:7}` from an offset of `i+1` with a length of 7 or else the end of the string).
- The third line executes it for the password `abcdefg`

The above code is for `bash` **only**.  Here is the `zsh` version:

```
$ pwmorph() { for i in {1..7}; do echo "${1[0,i-1]}${(U)1[i]}${1[i+1,7]}"; done; }
$ pwmorph abcdefg
```

`zsh` doesn't need an uppercase function (`${(U)VAR}` is the uppercase version of `$VAR`) and its indices start with `1` rather than `0` like `bash`.  Variable substrings are called differently as well.