# Customize John The Ripper BF technique

Tags: brute-force, password-cracking, wpa2-psk, hashcat

Is it possible for me to customize the way John the Ripper brute forces a `.cap` file? I, knowing my WiFi password, want to crack it fast as possible (no hit with word list).

Can I customize John to only try with 4 numbers and 5 letters in a 9 character password?

I've searched and read a lot of posts, but nothing seems to match my question. Also, doesn't matter if it's John, Hashcat or any other cracker.

Comment: Check http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47416/cracking-passwords-after-a-pattern-with-john

Comment: The thing is i dont know if it's ?u?l?l?l?d?d?d, like the example in the linked thread. I just know it's 4 number and 5 letters. I do not know the order.

Answer (score 2):

There's no native way to create a single variable-content mask with John or hashcat. Instead, you can generate a set of all possible masks that fit your criteria. See [my answer here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/158968/6203).

In your case, the policygen command might look something like the following (assuming lower case):

```
$ policygen --minlength=9 --maxlength=9 \
  --mindigit=4 --maxdigit 4 --minlower=5 --maxlower 5 \
  --maxupper=0 --maxspecial=0 -o target.masks
```