# How to configure hashcat to only hash fixed length passwords with N digits?

Tags: brute-force, hashcat

I know of mask and dictionary attacks.

Using a mask attack, I specify the charset for each position in the password pattern, e.g., ?1?1?d?1?d?1?1?d, where ?1 := ?l?u?s.

But how do I tell hashcat to only hash (fixed length) passwords with at least N digits (?d)? That is, the ?d charset specifiers may float around in the pattern above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native way to do this with hashcat. Instead, you must generate a list of masks that contain all of the permutations that fit your criteria.

The common tool for this is [policygen](http://thesprawl.org/projects/pack/#policygen) from the PACK toolkit. [My answer here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/158968/6203) outlines how to use it.

For your use case, it would be something like this (assuming 8-character passwords and a minimum of 3 digits):

```
$ policygen --minlength=8 --maxlength=8  --mindigit=3 \
    -o len8mindigit3.masks

               _ 
     PolicyGen 0.0.2  | |
      _ __   __ _  ___| | _
     | '_ \ / _` |/ __| |/ /
     | |_) | (_| | (__|   < 
     | .__/ \__,_|\___|_|\_\
     | |                    
     |_| iphelix@thesprawl.org


[*] Saving generated masks to [len8mindigit3.masks]
[*] Using 1,000,000,000 keys/sec for calculations.
[*] Password policy:
    Pass Lengths: min:8 max:8
    Min strength: l:None u:None d:3 s:None
    Max strength: l:None u:None d:None s:None
[*] Generating [compliant] masks.
[*] Generating 8 character password masks.
[*] Total Masks:  65536 Time: 76 days, 18:50:04
[*] Policy Masks: 21067 Time: 3 days, 8:11:03

$ head len8mindigit3.masks
?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?l
?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?u
?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?s
?d?d?d?d?d?d?l?d
?d?d?d?d?d?d?l?l
?d?d?d?d?d?d?l?u
?d?d?d?d?d?d?l?s
?d?d?d?d?d?d?u?d
?d?d?d?d?d?d?u?l

$ tail len8mindigit3.masks
?s?s?s?s?d?d?d?s
?s?s?s?s?d?d?l?d
?s?s?s?s?d?d?u?d
?s?s?s?s?d?d?s?d
?s?s?s?s?d?l?d?d
?s?s?s?s?d?u?d?d
?s?s?s?s?d?s?d?d
?s?s?s?s?l?d?d?d
?s?s?s?s?u?d?d?d
?s?s?s?s?s?d?d?d
```

You would then supply that file of masks to hashcat.

Comment: Thank you - do you know if John the Ripper supports floating charset specifiers?

Comment: I think JtR has the same capability.

Comment: I meant if JtR supports floating charset specifiers instead of multiple masks? I will definitely try out Pack :) Do multiple masks provide huge overhead on the hashcat engine? That is, does switching masks take “long” time?

Comment: I meant that JtR and hashcat are the same - JtR also does not support such floating specifiers as far as I am aware. And on hashcat, there is a small performance cost - a second or two between each mask. so if your results are large, compressing them to use only a non-digit charset (?l?u?s) may be somewhat more efficient.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by compressing. Would you instead of specifying at least one of ?l, ?u, and ?s, say that the candidates much contain at least three -1 ?l?u?s..? I cannot see Pack supports this?

Comment: Furthermore, the "Guess.Queue......: 6/186480 (0.00%)" describes the current mask in the mask list, right? Can hashcat provide me with an approximation of total time? Right now, the estimation is per mask.

Comment: Here is a simple example. You can take these three masks: ?d?d?l, ?d?d?u, ?d?d?s and replace them with the single mask and custom charset -2 ?l?u?s ?d?d?2. See https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack#custom_charsets

Comment: Is there any tools to make such (optimal) transformations to reduce the number of masks?