# Specify Amount of type of character Crunch

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, crunch, wordlist

I'm sure these questions pop up a lot, but I can't find one that does what I'm looking for.
So, I'm trying to use crunch to generate a wordlist with specific amounts of each type of character, i.e. 2 numbers, 1 symbol, 3 uppercase, 1 lowercase, etc.
There are is -d, which seems to do what I cant, but it's for consecutive duplicates, which is not what I want.
The characters can be anywhere in the string, but there must be at least the specified amount of each type.
Is this possible?

Comment: I haven't seen what you are asking for. What I have done previously is generate large wordlists and then parse using regular expressions for whatever outcome I needed.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this with Crunch that I'm aware of.

The only way I know of to do this is the generate all masks that conform to the composition rules using the `policygen` tool from the PACK toolkit, as described in [my answer here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158956/bruteforce-with-hashcat-how-to-set-the-mask-properly/158968).

In your case, it would be something like:

```
$ policygen --minlength=8 --maxlength=12 \
  --mindigit=2 --minlower=1 --minupper=3 --minspecial=1 -o test1.masks
```

You'll have to adjust the minimum and maximum password length accordingly. The number of masks can go up rapidly with the maximum length, so adjust carefully.